# How to Remove or disable startapp ads from project

Tags: java, xml, project, disabled-input, startapp

How to Remove or disable startapp ads from project
[enter link description here](http://shop.arian-it.ir/AndroidManifest.xml)

[enter link description here](http://shop.arian-it.ir/homescreen.xml)

Comment: Please be specific of the question you are asking and specify the things that are related.

Answer (score 0):

go etc/hosts or \Windows\System32\driver\etc\hosts and enter the following line:

```
127.0.0.1    google.analytics // redirect link to local host
127.0.0.1    shop.arian-it.ir // for your site
```

add a line for each site you don't want.

Comment: How to Remove or disable startapp ads from project startapp ads sdk

Answer (score 0):

There is `StartAppInApp-3.5.6.jar` inside your project, may be having different version. Find it inside your project and remove it. This jar may be inside libs folder in your project.

When you remove your jar, you see lots of error inside your project. Remove that buggy lines, Some of them are below.

```
public StartAppAd startAppAd;

StartAppSDK.init(HomeScreen.this, "204893117", true);
startAppAd = new StartAppAd(HomeScreen.this);
startAppAd.loadAd(new AdEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
            startAppAd.showAd();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

And remove these activities entries from `AndoridMainifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />

<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.FullScreenActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable return ads please updating your AndroidManifest.xml in meta-data tag :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.startapp.sdk.RETURN_ADS_ENABLED"
        android:value="false" />
```

[Ref to support.start.io](https://support.start.io/hc/en-us/articles/360011385820-Manual-Integration-with-JAR-File#addingsdktoyourproject)